# Open xpage document from view in cliente Notes

Tags: xpages, xpinc, notesview

I need to open a document in an xpage in the browser from a document in the notes client. If I click on the view I open the document in the associated xpage, however in the xpinc client. Is there a way, which is not redirected to the browser from a code in xpage events?

Comment: Have you tried to open a url to that XPage if you click on the document? That should launch the configured browser. Note that you then also need to authenticate.

Comment: Is there any function to identify that I'm in xping to redirect to the browser? Would you put the redirect on which event, form notes, xpage or view? What would be the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of auto-launching the XPage, open the url via code in your form.

```
Sub Postopen(Source As Notesuidocument)
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace  
    Call  ws .URLOpen(<computed url to XPAGE>)
    source.Close
End Sub
```

You must do this in Postopen, because URLOpen does not work in the Queryopen.

Comment: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/dba3ca7e515d55ff85256a0700727b35/22b76f7f0197a9af852578f50057e8d0?OpenDocument